# iOS - Creating a SpringBoard screen

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, springboard

I'm trying so create a collection view that behaves like the iOS springboard screen.
That means that I want to have a collection view, with all of my items, and to have a page controller underneath the grid (just like the springboard screen). I also want to implement the same edit mode, meaning that one my icons are in edit mode, I can drag them from one page to another, in such a way that a page doesn't have to be full.
I've tried to set a single collection view to scroll horizontally, but it doesn't act as I want. first of all, the icons are added one *below* the other, instead of one *beside* the other. secondly, I don't have the page dots this way, and the user can't put icons on different pages
I also tried to set a page controller, and put in every page the collection view. In this case, I get that while in edit mode, I can't go between screens. I guess that is because I have more that one collection view, and they don't interact with each other.
I though of another way, of using a scroll view, and try to put a collection view inside that scroll view. But it sounds to me like a very not elegant solution.

Does anyone have an idea about how to create such a scene?

Edit:
I think the answer for my problem is hiding in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719196/reorder-cells-of-uicollectionview?answertab=active#tab-top). It describes the same situation I want to have: a collection view, that is scrolled horizontally, with paging, and that the order of the icons is not flowing vertically, but also flowing horizontally. There is a partially good answer there. I say it's partially good since the answer describes a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout, but in the sample project uploaded the subclass is of UICollectionViewLayout, and I think the whole point was to maintain the functions that the UICollectionViewFlowLayout has.
This question was asked a year ago, so I believe someone has an answer, or at least, I hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have partial solution to my question.
I did use the answer (of Bogdan) to the [linked question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719196/reorder-cells-of-uicollectionview?answertab=active#tab-top). Here's the code:

layout.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface V9Layout : UICollectionViewLayout

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger itemsInOneRow;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger itemsInOneCol;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGSize itemSize;

@end
```

layout.m:

```
#import "V9Layout.h"

@interface V9Layout()

-(void)calculateLayoutProperties;
-(int)pagesInSection:(NSInteger)section;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *frames;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat lineSpacing;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat interitemSpacing;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGSize pageSize;    
@end

@implementation V9Layout

@synthesize itemsInOneRow = _itemsInOneRow, itemsInOneCol = _itemsInOneCol, itemSize = _itemSize;
@synthesize lineSpacing = _lineSpacing, interitemSpacing = _interitemSpacing;
@synthesize frames = _frames;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    self.itemsInOneRow = 3;
    self.itemsInOneCol = 4;
    self.frames = [NSMutableArray array];
}

-(void)calculateLayoutProperties {
    self.pageSize = self.collectionView.bounds.size;

    // The width of all line spacings is equal to width of ONE item. The same for interitem spacing

    CGFloat itemWidth = self.pageSize.width / (self.itemsInOneRow + 1); // +1 because we all spaces make width of one additional item
    CGFloat itemHeight = self.pageSize.height / (self.itemsInOneCol + 1); // the same
    NSLog(@"calculateLayoutProperties item width: %f, item height: %f", itemWidth, itemHeight);

    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(itemWidth, itemHeight);
    // this part is only to make a global parameter, because I'm using this data to create the size of the UICollectionViewCell. I think I need to use a delegate method for the UICollectionViewCell to ask the UICollectionViewLayout for the calculated size of cell.
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:itemWidth] forKey:@"cellWidth"];
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:itemHeight] forKey:@"cellHeight"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }

    // spacing for x
    self.lineSpacing = (self.pageSize.width - (self.itemsInOneRow * self.itemSize.width)) / (self.itemsInOneRow + 1);
    // spacing for y
    self.interitemSpacing = (self.pageSize.height - (self.itemsInOneCol * self.itemSize.height)) / (self.itemsInOneCol + 1);
}

-(int)pagesInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"v9layout: numberOfItemsInSection is %ld", (long)[self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section]);
    return ([self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 1) / (self.itemsInOneRow * self.itemsInOneCol)  + 1;
}

-(CGSize)collectionViewContentSize {
    // contentSize.width is equal to pages * pageSize.width
    NSInteger sections = 1;
    if ([self.collectionView respondsToSelector:@selector(numberOfSections)]) {
        sections = [self.collectionView numberOfSections];
    }
    int pages = 0;
    for (int section = 0; section < sections; section++) {
        pages = pages + [self pagesInSection:section];
    }
    return CGSizeMake(pages * self.pageSize.width, self.pageSize.height);
}

-(void)prepareLayout {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [self calculateLayoutProperties];
    });

    [self.frames removeAllObjects];

    NSInteger sections = 1;
    if ([self.collectionView respondsToSelector:@selector(numberOfSections)]) {
        sections = [self.collectionView numberOfSections];
    }
    int pagesOffset = 0; // Pages that are used by prevoius sections
    int itemsInPage = self.itemsInOneRow * self.itemsInOneCol;
    for (int section = 0; section < sections; section++) {
        NSMutableArray *framesInSection = [NSMutableArray array];
        int pagesInSection = [self pagesInSection:section];
        int itemsInSection = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];
        for (int page = 0; page < pagesInSection; page++) {
            int itemsToAddToArray = itemsInSection - framesInSection.count;
            int itemsInCurrentPage = itemsInPage;
            if (itemsToAddToArray < itemsInPage) { // If there are less cells than expected (typically last page of section), we go only through existing cells.
                itemsInCurrentPage = itemsToAddToArray;
            }
            for (int itemInPage = 0; itemInPage < itemsInCurrentPage; itemInPage++) {
                CGFloat originX = (pagesOffset + page) * self.pageSize.width + self.lineSpacing + (itemInPage % self.itemsInOneRow) * (self.itemSize.width + self.lineSpacing);
                CGFloat originY = self.interitemSpacing + (itemInPage / self.itemsInOneRow) * (self.itemSize.height + self.interitemSpacing);
                CGRect itemFrame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, self.itemSize.width, self.itemSize.height);
                [framesInSection addObject:NSStringFromCGRect(itemFrame)];
            }
        }
        [self.frames addObject:framesInSection];

        pagesOffset += pagesInSection;
    }
}

-(NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSMutableArray *attributes = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSInteger sections = 1;
    if ([self.collectionView respondsToSelector:@selector(numberOfSections)]) {
        sections = [self.collectionView numberOfSections];
    }

    int pagesOffset = 0;
    int itemsInPage = self.itemsInOneRow * self.itemsInOneCol;
    for (int section = 0; section < sections; section++) {
        int pagesInSection = [self pagesInSection:section];
        int itemsInSection = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];
        for (int page = 0; page < pagesInSection; page++) {
            CGRect pageFrame = CGRectMake((pagesOffset + page) * self.pageSize.width, 0, self.pageSize.width, self.pageSize.height);

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, pageFrame)) {
                int startItemIndex = page * itemsInPage;
                int itemsInCurrentPage = itemsInPage;
                if (itemsInSection - startItemIndex < itemsInPage) {
                    itemsInCurrentPage = itemsInSection - startItemIndex;
                }
                for (int itemInPage = 0; itemInPage < itemsInCurrentPage; itemInPage++) {
                    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *itemAttributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:startItemIndex + itemInPage inSection:section]];
                    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(itemAttributes.frame, rect)) {
                        [attributes addObject:itemAttributes];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        pagesOffset += pagesInSection;
    }
    return attributes;
}

-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    attributes.frame = CGRectFromString(self.frames[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]);
    return attributes;
}

@end
```

This implement the horizontal paging with order of cells one beside each other and not one underneath each other.
I still want to add a drag and drop ability so that the user can change the order of cells. I poset [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091400/ios-uicollectionviewlayout-change-cells-order-using-drag-and-drop) about it.
Hopefully, I'll find answer to this and update this answer.